# Arduino's Serial port need a println to read

Tags: arduino, serial-port, buffer

I need to use the method `Serial.println()` to read the serial buffer correctly. Without `Serial.println()` it does not read it.

A frame is received, which has a sync `byte`, a `byte` that is the sender address, a `byte` that is the destination address and a data `byte`

```
void client(){

  String string, ax,aux;
  char ax1,ax2,ax3,ax4;
  string="";
  ax="o1"; //the character is for frame synchronization and 1 is the client's address
  aux="";
  while (Serial.available() > 0) {
    char c= Serial.read();
    string=string+c;
    Serial.println(c); //without this line the code does not work
  }

  aux=string;   
  ax1=string[0]; //sync byte
  string="";;
  string=aux;
  ax2=string[1]; //sender address byte
  string="";;
  string=aux;
  ax3=string[2];// destination address byte
  string="";;
  string=aux;
  ax4=string[3]; //data byte
  string="";;
  string=aux;
  Serial.println(string); //without this line the code does not work

              if (ax1==ax[0] && ax3==ax[1] && ax4=='1'){
                digitalWrite(A0,HIGH);
              }
               if (ax1==ax[0] && ax3==ax[1] && ax4=='0'){
                digitalWrite(A0,LOW);
              }
}
```

Comment: What is at the other end of the link? Are you sure you're not reading back your own echo?

Comment: What is your problem and what do you mean by "Code not work"?

Comment: Souldnt you be using the wire class?

Comment: String is empty in the while sentence if there isnt Serial.println(c). It doesnt get the buffer's data

Comment: For testing purposes, try replacing the println with a delay of one bit in the serial communication. Probably you're reading the available bytes before a new byte comes to the buffer, and adding the println implicitly adds the delay.

Comment: I could fix it with Serial.readString() instead Serial.read(). I still dont know why because the emitter sends chars.